# Show a grid similar to an alert

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to show alert but there I could not add ion-select, so I created a grid and I need to show that grid in the center of a page and the background should be disabled.

```
<ion-grid  class="showmodal" *ngIf="showNews" style=" background:white; width:50%; height:60%">
    <ion-row>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

I tried the possible CSS and I am able to get the grid but it's not going to center

```
 .showmodal{
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background: rgba(23, 22, 22, 0.8);
        z-index: 10;
        left: 0px;
    }
```

this grid should be always in the center even if screen size differs.

Answer (score 1):

Since its height and width is fixed you can use the CSS as:

```
 .showmodal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a parent div and add stylings accordingly.

```css
.showmodal{ 
height: 100px; 
color: white;
width: 100px; 
background: steelblue; 
margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 15%;
}
.parent{
position: fixed; 
top: 0; 
z-index: 10; 
left: 0px; 
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: rgba(23, 22, 22, 0.8); 
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" ><div class="showmodal" > content </div> </div>
```